# Node js Unit test sinon chai

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, sinon, chai

How to create unit test for the bellow file

**index.ts**

```
import ----
import ----

let workerService = new WorkerService();
let creatWorkerPromise = Promise.promisify(workerService.createWorkers);

creatWorkerPromise()
.then(function(){
    let kafkaService =  new KafkaService(kafkaConfig, workerService);
})
.catch(function (err: any) {
    console.log('Error while creating workers:', err);
});
```

Comment: Your question is too unclear to be answered. A unit test is supposed to answer some question. What are you trying to test? Do you want to test that `KafkaService` is being called with a certain config, or what? And if this is a module, then what is its API?

Comment: thanks @oligofren here I want to test 2 conditions, 1. if it is success console.log should not call, 2. if it fail console.log should be called

Answer (score 1):

It's kind of difficult to test something that is not a unit, as a unit usually exposes methods that are to be tested, so I am assuming that you do this eventually in the test code. So here goes:

```js
///////////
// index.js
///////////
// stubs for this example to work
var createWorkerPromise = function(){ return Promise.resolve(); }
var workerService, kafkaConfig;
function KafkaService(){ throw new Error("crashes test"); }

function exportedFunction(){ 
  return createWorkerPromise()
    .then(function(){
        var kafkaService =  new KafkaService(kafkaConfig, workerService);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log('Error while creating workers:', err);
    });
}

///////////
// test.js
///////////
var log = console.log.bind(console);
var assert = function(expr) {
  if(!expr) throw new Error("AssertionError"); 
  log("TEST OK");
}

// the test
var spy = sinon.spy(console, 'log');
exportedFunction().then(function test() {
  assert(spy.called);
  
}).catch(log.bind(null, "TEST FAILED"))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sinon@latest/pkg/sinon.js"></script>
```

Comment: you might also be interested in http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/. if my answer solves your question, consider marking it as the solution